# How can we access an unnamed namespace outside the file it is created in?

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

I was reading online about namespaces, and read about unnamed namespaces. I read that unnamed namespaces are only accessible within the file they were created in. But when I tried it on my own, it didn't work like that. How is that possible?

Here is what I did:

file1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace space1 {
    int a = 10;
    void f() {
        cout << "in space1 of code 1" << endl;
    };
}

namespace {
    int x = 20;
    void f() {
        cout << "in unnamed space" << endl;
    }
}
```

file2: where I accessed the namespace from file1

```
#include <iostream>
#include "code1.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    space1::f();
    cout << space1::a;
    cout << x << endl;
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include "code1.cpp"` makes it the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we access the unnamed namespaces outside the file they were created?

Depends on which "file" you're referring to. If you refer to the header file, then yes you can access the unnamed namespace outside, since the unnamed namespace is available to the entire translation unit that includes the header.

If you refer to the entire translation unit then no, the unnamed namespace cannot be accessed from other translation units.

Comment: @RetiredNinja `they are including the first cpp file` If they include a file into another, then that included file is a "header". Using .cpp suffix for a header file is a bad idea though. I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

You read that an unnamed namespace is limited to the **file** that creates it.  That is not true. It is limited to the **translation unit** that creates it.

During the preprocessor stage, your `#include "code1.cpp"` statement in `file2` brings all of the code of `code1.cpp` into the code of `file2`. Thus, when `file2` is compiled, both codes are part of the same translation unit, which is why the unnamed namespace in `code1.cpp` is accessible to `file2`'s code.